# Регулярные выражения на Java - как правильно настроить фильтр?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, файлы, csv

Здравствуйте!

Если в файле нет пробелов и всяческих спец символов, то все работает прекрасно. Но стоит в каком-то слове повстречаться: пробел, спец символы и т.п. ,то возникает ошибка. Файл формата CSV. Мне нужно, чтобы каждая строка в файле являлась отдельной ячейкой.

```
Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);

String[] values; String wordName; Integer wordSum;

while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
    values = inputStream.next().split(";");
    wordName = values[0];
    wordSum = Integer.parseInt(values[3]);
```

[image: Вот файл с которым я работаю с помощью фильтра]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68222/discussion-on-question-by-vaagn-akopyan----java--).

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решается либо использование `BufferedReader`, либо изменением делителя у `Scenner` через метод `Scenner.useDelimiter()`, указав как разделитель `System.lineSeparator()`. Если интересно, то несколько примеров внизу.

---

Если честно, никогда не пользуюсь Scanner поэтому ответить почему это происходит не смогу, но если использовать BufferedReader все работает нормально, расставил проблемы в рандомных местах и все равно работает.

[image: результат работы BufferedReader]

```
static File stackOverFlow = new File("C:\\Downloads\\d.csv");
try(BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stackOverFlow))){
            String s;
            while( (s = read.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = s.split(";");
                System.out.printf("0-[%s] 1-[%s] 2-[%s] 3-[%s]\n", split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3]);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

и вывод:

```
0-[B ob] 1-[Создан] 2-[03.11.201 712:05: 0 0] 3-[3]
0-[Gar ry] 1-[Соз дан] 2-[03.11.201712:05: 0 0] 3-[4]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

Решил протестировать и показать все 3 потока на одном файле.

**Содержимое файла:**

```
B ob;Создан;03.11.201 712:05: 0 0;3
Gar ry;Соз дан;03.11.201712:05: 0 0;4
```

**Код:**

```
public class ReadCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File stackOverFlow = new File("C:\\Downloads\\d.csv");

        System.out.println("==================================");
        System.out.println("Scanner");
        System.out.println("==================================");
        try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(stackOverFlow)){
            while(sc.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(sc.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("==================================");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("FileInputStream");
        System.out.println("==================================");
        try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(stackOverFlow)){
            byte[] mass = new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(mass);
            System.out.println(new String(mass));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("==================================");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("BufferedReader");
        System.out.println("==================================");
        try(BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stackOverFlow))){
            String s;
            while( (s = read.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("==================================");
    }
}
```

**И соответствующий вывод:**

```
==================================
Scanner
==================================
B
ob;Создан;03.11.201
712:05:
0
0;3
Gar
ry;Соз
дан;03.11.201712:05:
0
0;4
==================================

FileInputStream
==================================
B ob;Создан;03.11.201 712:05: 0 0;3
Gar ry;Соз дан;03.11.201712:05: 0 0;4

==================================

BufferedReader
==================================
B ob;Создан;03.11.201 712:05: 0 0;3
Gar ry;Соз дан;03.11.201712:05: 0 0;4
==================================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

Оказывается, чтобы избежать этой проблемы (Когда сканер делит строки по пробелу), надо просто указать, чтобы он делил по перевод строки.

Изменив, в коде сверху, блок кода со сканером на такой:

```
try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(stackOverFlow)){
            sc.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
            while(sc.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(sc.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

получаем корректный вывод:

```
==================================
Scanner
==================================
B ob;Создан;03.11.201 712:05: 0 0;3
Gar ry;Соз дан;03.11.201712:05: 0 0;4
==================================

FileInputStream
==================================
B ob;Создан;03.11.201 712:05: 0 0;3
Gar ry;Соз дан;03.11.201712:05: 0 0;4

==================================

BufferedReader
==================================
B ob;Создан;03.11.201 712:05: 0 0;3
Gar ry;Соз дан;03.11.201712:05: 0 0;4
==================================
```

---

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное Виктор, с пробелом, который был в колонке С я избавился, а вот с пробелом в колонке B проблема остается (выдает пустой результат), вот мой код:  https://yadi.sk/i/xOy_pnbs3PR7zU    Можешь скоректировать ее?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8jZCDCBT заменить свой try на этот и скиньте вывод, т.к. у меня вполне спокойно строка делиться на 4 элемента и к каждому я могу обратиться

Comment: не очень понял, что значит скинуть вывод, но код твой вставил (заменил Try).  Ругается, не понимает, что такоеstackOverFlow ( 23 строка ) . Если заменить это слово переменной file , то выводится пустое значение.   Вот код и скрин https://yadi.sk/i/xOy_pnbs3PR7zU https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/11/5/750fa487eba0b6bdd2d14ca1036c4b20-full.png

Comment: опубликуйте проект на github.com или скиньте архив с проектом (яндекс\гугл диск), т.к. у меня данный код работает, может проблема где-то в другом месте

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/fGzP-FgT3PRAdm   Да и кстати забыл сказать , по новому коду,  если все без пробелов, то выводит только суммы из D по каждому сотруднику, но не выводит количество раз по которому слово встречается ( раньше все было гуд).

Comment: похоже проблема не в коде, а какая-то сторонняя. Запустил ваш код на вашем оригинальном файле, результат -> https://prnt.sc/h6bllu Так же запустил с модифицированным(где добавлял пробелы) результат -> https://prnt.sc/h6bkq2 попробуйте использовать не сканер а bufferedReader, если результат так же будет пустой, значит проблема точно не в коде

Comment: Можете export settings сделать вашего IntelenjIDE?  Попробую вставить настройки вашего IDE к себе

Comment: держите =) https://yadi.sk/d/4X4SMKnA3PRBRi

Comment: Виктор, спасибо за ваши усердия. Дело было в неправильных настройках версии компилятора. Удалил все и заново установил - заработало. Теперь остался последний вопрос как мне сделать так, чтобы программа выводила количество раз когда встречается то или иное слово и сумму чисел (из последней колонки) по конкретному слову?

Comment: предлагаю перейти в созданный нам чат =) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68222/discussion-on-question-by-vaagn-akopyan----java--